# 無線LANインターフェスをブリッジインタフェースに追加できません。

Tags: linux

linux(Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS)で無線LANインターフェスをブリッジインタフェースに追加できません。

```
# brctl addbr br0
# brctl addif br0 wlp1s0
can't add wlp1s0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

`wlp1s0`は無線LANのインタフェースです。

PCはSurface pro3で無線LANは`mwifiex_pcie`です。

どのようにすればブリッジインタフェースに追加することができるでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己回答です、

linuxカーネルのソースを見ていたら
`net/wireless/core.c`のコード

```
if ((wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_STATION ||
     wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_P2P_CLIENT ||
     wdev->iftype == NL80211_IFTYPE_ADHOC) && !wdev->use_4addr)
    dev->priv_flags |= IFF_DONT_BRIDGE;
```

となっているので無線LANインタフェースはブリッジに追加できないようにしているようです。
カーネルを修正する以外に方法は無いみたいです。