# セキュアブート可能なlinuxカーネルイメージパッケージの作成方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu16.04.4 LTSをMicrosoft Surface pro 3 で使用しています。
[無線LANインターフェスをブリッジインタフェースに追加できません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43264/%E7%84%A1%E7%B7%9Alan%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)
にある目的でカーネルを修正して.debパッケージを作成しようとしています。

まずは修正せずにパッケージをビルドしてインストール - ブートできるかを確認します

```
$ apt source linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic
$ dpkg-buildpackage -B
```

これでカーネルイメージのパッケージが作成されました。
つづいてパッケージをインストールします。

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic_4.13.0-38.43~16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

インストールも無事成功し、ブートしましたがセキュアブートに阻まれてブートできませんでした。
セキュアブートを無効にすればブートするでしょうが、Surfaceはセキュアブートを無効にすると
真っ赤なパワーオンロゴを出すといういじわるをするのでセキュアブートは有効なままでブートしたいです。

ビルドしたカーネルをセキュアブートでブートするためには
手順として、署名をする必要がありそうなことは想像つきます。
おそらく想像するに
　１．証明書と秘密鍵を自前で生成
　2.署名する(おそらく *.koも)
　3.証明書をUEFIにインストールする
という手順が必要かと考えています。

しかし具体的にどういう操作をすればいいのか見当もつきません。
ダウンロードしたソースのどこかに証明書と秘密鍵を置けば勝手にしてくれるのか…
想像している手順を自前でしなくてなならないのか…

ちなみに、surfaceにubuntuをインストールしてVirtualBoxでゲストOS:Windows10を起動する
といういびつな使い方をしています。
VirtualBoxのドライバをmodprobeする際もセキュアブートに阻まれて
https://askubuntu.com/a/900121
を参考に無事セキュアブートでもmodprobeできたという経験はあります。

質問：
ビルドしたカーネルをセキュアブートでブートできるようにするにはどういう操作をすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88

↑これは archlinux 用の wiki ですが、参考になると思います。

「手動でダウンロード」の link から、署名済みの  PreLoader.efi と HashTool.efi をダウンロードできます。

- PreLoader は署名されているので、これは secure boot で起動できる。
- PreLoader は boot loader (systemd-boot や grub 等) を読み込んで起動する。
- boot loader は kernel image を読み込んで起動する。

という流れで、もし途中で security error が発生した場合は、その場で署名済み HashTool が起動し、ユーザがその場でファイル名を指定して enroll することができます。enroll すればそのバイナリは起動できます。また、`*.ko` の読み込みについては、既に secure boot とは無関係の処理ですので、何もすることなく読み込んでくれます。

私はこの方法を使っていますが、
この流れでは、kernel image を作った時に署名するのでなく、boot 時に enroll していますので、kernel image を作った後 enroll するまでに改竄されることに対しては無力です。

secure boot に対応したい理由が、

> Surfaceはセキュアブートを無効にすると真っ赤なパワーオンロゴを出すといういじわるをするので

なので、上記方法で問題ないと思いますが、もしそうではなく、やはり自前で署名したいということであれば、
上記のページに「自分で署名した鍵を使う」という項目があり、
この方法を使えば、作った kernel image にすぐに署名できるのだと思いますが、
私はやったことがないので詳細は知りません。